# Application doesn't appear in Android Market for a certain device (Android Market Filters)

Tags: android, android-manifest

I have some problems with Android Market filtering system. I have been
reading the documentation about Android Market Filters in
developer.android.com, and I suppose the problem is related with
screen or density restrictions.

The manifest of my application contains the following:

- uses-permission ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION
- uses-permission INTERNET
- uses-permission READ_PHONE_STATE
- uses-permission SEND_SMS
- uses-permission ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION
- uses-permission ACCESS_COARSE_UPDATES
- uses-permission RECEIVE_SMS
- uses-permission ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE
- uses-permission WAKE_LOCK
- uses-permission WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE
- minSdkVersion is 7

Looking to this uses permissions it is clear that Android Market will
restrict the app to those devices which don't have either GPS, 3G/
WiFi, Telephony or SD storage.

However, I have a Motorola Xoom tablet (Android 3.1) which has all
these hardware capabilities and it is unable to see my app in the
Android Market.

I'm not declaring any supported screen by means of 
element, because when the android:minSdkVersion is set to 4 or higher,
the application is considered to support all screen sizes by default.
But my application is based on API level 7 and android:xlargeScreens
attribute doesn't appear until API level 9.

Any idea?

Thanks in advance.

Xavi Barrera Quintanilla

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can have `minSdkVersion` set to 7, but build with `targetSdkVersion=9` and `target=android-9` and than the application will still run on devices with api-level 7, but you can use the attributes defined in api-level 9. So you can set `android:xlargeScreens` while still keeping the application compatible with 2.1.

The disadvantage is that now the IDE will consider anything available at api-level 9 as valid and than the application will fail at runtime if run on a device with older firmware. We work this around by doing development builds with the target set to minSdkVersion and release builds with modified manifest and target set to the version we use the attributes from.

Comment: So the problem could be the not declaration of the android:xlargeScreens attribute, right? I could try putting target as API level 9, but I want to be sure before uploading a new version to Android Market.

Comment: @xavibarrera: I don't really know, I didn't try it (unfortunately we don't have any 3.x tablets here, though we really should). But if you have `<supports-screens>` and don't have `xlargeScreens`, than android 3.1, which does not yet have the screen compatibility mode (implemented in 3.2) may not like such package.

Answer (score 1):

I just confirmed that [Jan Hudec's solution](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8800273/application-doesnt-appear-in-android-market-for-a-certain-device-android-marke/8801397#8801397) works, you have to set `android:xlargescreens` to true in order for your app to not be filtered for **ANY 10 inch tablet**, regardless of Android OS version. We luckily had 3 different 10 inch tablets, and one 7 inch, at my work place available to test this on. The Asus Transformer and Nexus 10 running Jelly Bean, and a Galaxy Tab 10.1 running Honeycomb were all listed as incompatible devices, but our Nexus 7 was compatible.

Be sure to also set the `targetSdkVersion` (the documentation recommends you set this explicitly) probably to 8 or above, and the `minSdkVersion` is ok at 7 or above.

Unfortunately, before I set `android:xlargeScreens` to true, while publishing the app in the Android developer console, I was still seeing that the Galaxy Tab 10.1, Nexus 10, etc. were all listed as supported devices. So it wasn't until the app showed up in the Play store that it claimed the app was incompatible with those tablets. It's possible the developer console only checks the `minSdkVersion` in the manifest, and not supported screens.

Comment: I can confirm that adding targetSdkVersion with a value greater or equal to 11 works, that is all I was required to do.