# My app is not available for tablet device on Google play

Tags: android, publish, google-play

I published my app 2 days ago on Google Play.
For some reasons i can only see it in my phone's Google Play.
If i search it on my Samsung Galaxy Tab, it does not appear.

In manifest.xml i didnt wrote anything like:

```
 android:largeScreens="false"
```

in addition, this tag is set "true" by default, as far as i know.

Can anybody tell me something about this issue?

On Web browser's Google play i see this info:

This app is compatible with some of your devices.

-Samsung GT-P7500
This item is not compatible with your device.

-Vodafone Samsung GT-I9000

-HTC HTC Sensation Z710e

= = = E D I T = = 
This is my manifest just as you asked:

I use phone calls and telephony manager too.. could this be the problem? 
I must make an other version only for tabs or what ?

Maybe `android:largeScreens="false"`  this is default ?

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="com.KeySoft.OpenGuide"
    android:versionCode="2"
    android:versionName="1.1" >
   <uses-library android:name="com.google.android.maps" />

    <uses-sdk android:minSdkVersion="10" />

    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE"/>
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION"/>
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.CALL_PHONE"/>
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_PHONE_STATE"/>
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE"/>
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION"/>"
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCES_LOCATION_EXTRA_COMMANDS"/>
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_MOCK_LOCATION"/>   
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.CONTROL_LOCATION_UPDATES"/>   

    <application
       android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher"
       android:label="@string/app_name" >
    <uses-library android:name="com.google.android.maps" />

         <activity
            android:name=".LoadingScreen"
            android:theme="@android:style/Theme.NoTitleBar"
            android:label="@string/app_name" >
         <intent-filter>
         <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
         <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
         </intent-filter>
         </activity>


         <activity 
         android:name="Top20"
         android:theme="@android:style/Theme.NoTitleBar">
         </activity>

         <activity 
         android:name="ShopActivity"
         android:theme="@android:style/Theme.NoTitleBar">
         </activity>

         <activity 
         android:name="Highlighted"
         android:theme="@android:style/Theme.NoTitleBar">
         </activity>

         <activity 
         android:name="Favourites"
         android:theme="@android:style/Theme.NoTitleBar">
         </activity>

         <activity 
         android:name="Near"
         android:theme="@android:style/Theme.NoTitleBar">
         </activity>

         <activity 
         android:configChanges="keyboardHidden"
         android:windowSoftInputMode="stateHidden"
         android:name="Search"
         android:theme="@android:style/Theme.NoTitleBar">
         </activity>


    </application>

</manifest>
```

Answer (score 37, accepted):

The value is true if the "android:largeScreens" not declare in manifest.
Do you use any other features? For example, making a phone call.

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.CALL_PHONE"></uses-permission>
<uses-feature android:name="android.hardware.telephony" android:required="false"></uses-feature>
```

You may add this pair of statement to your manifest, it do not force the device support telephony. However, you may need to check whether the user can use that “calling” function in your activity, if they are using a device that do not support. For the other features that may be filter by Google Play, you may visit here: http://developer.android.com/guide/appendix/market-filters.html

Comment: <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.CALL_PHONE"></uses-permission> <uses-feature android:name="android.hardware.telephony" android:required="false"></uses-feature>

Comment: if i add these will my app appear on google play for tabs too ?

Comment: Great table showing permissions that imply feature requirements: http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/manifest/uses-feature-element.html#permissions

Answer (score 2):

You may be having the same issue as is mentioned here:
[Android Market: "This item is not compatible with your device."](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9471448/android-market-this-item-is-not-compatible-with-your-device/16655736#16655736)

In a nutshell, for 10 inch tablets, like the Samsung Galaxy Tab, you also have to set `xlargeScreens` to true.

It does appear, as was just mentioned in this discussion by Key, that Google Play recently implemented stricter filtering rules, and this `xlargeScreens` may be just one example.

Answer (score 1):

The developer documentation recommends explicitly adding this since it may vary across version

> android:largeScreens
>
> Indicates whether the application supports larger screen form-factors.
>   A large screen is defined as a screen that is significantly larger
>   than a "normal" handset screen, and thus might require some special
>   care on the application's part to make good use of it, though it may
>   rely on resizing by the system to fill the screen. The default value
>   for this actually varies between some versions, so it's better if you
>   explicitly declare this attribute at all times. Beware that setting it
>   "false" will generally enable screen compatibility mode.

Also make sure `android:minSdkVersion`, `android:targetSdkVersion` and `android:maxSdkVersion` are setup correctly.

Comment: What do you mean by:
"Also make sure android:minSdkVersion, android:targetSdkVersion and android:maxSdkVersion are setup correctly."

And from that text i just dont get it, i have to add android:largeScreens="true" or not? I publicated another app without this line and i can see that app in tab's google play system.

Comment: If you mean maybe tab's android version is too high, its just not. 
I got only this in manifest:
<uses-sdk android:minSdkVersion="10" />
It should be work on android 2.3+

Comment: Do you have any <uses-feature> elements in your manifest? PLay store filters on those too. For e.g. if you use android.hardware.telephony it filters most tablets. It would be easy if you just shared the relevant pieces of your manifest rather than us guessing.

Answer (score 1):

Seems like they recently have changed how strict the filter for tablet support is in Google Play? Was presented on the Google I/O 2013.

Answer (score 0):

I think , if you put this cod in your manifest , it will work correctly.

```
<supports-screens
    android:resizeable="true"
    android:smallScreens="true"
    android:normalScreens="true"
    android:largeScreens="true"
    android:xlargeScreens="true"
    android:anyDensity="true"/>
```