# How can I tell if my Android app will be available on Google Play for tablets?

Tags: android, google-play

A client of ours tried to find our app on Google Play using his tablet, but couldn't.

In my manifest file, I have phone permissions set up, like so:

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.CALL_PHONE" />
```

I'm assuming that most tablets don't support this. I'm also assuming that the Google Play filters are seeing this phone permission in my manifest file and are making the app invisible to devices that don't support it.

I read in the forums somewhere that if I add the following line to my manifest file, non-phone devices should be able to use it:

```
<uses-feature android:name="android.hardware.telephony" android:required="false"></uses-feature>
```

Is this accurate? Will this allow my application to be seen on Google Play by tablets?

I don't have an Android tablet in the office that I can test on, is there a better way to tell if an app will be visible to tablets on Google Play?

Answer (score 3):

From Google's [Tablet App Quality Checklist](http://developer.android.com/distribute/googleplay/quality/tablet.html#google-play) section on the Play Store, they say you should be able to check the complete list of APK device compatiblity in the developer console.

Specifically (using the "new design" console as of Nov 2012), click the "APK" section for your application, then see the "Supported Devices" section.  Click "See Supported Devices" to see a long list of devices (there are currently 2116 devices listed!).  You can see the list by supported or unsupported devices.  There isn't any detail in here that says "tablets" or why any particular device is listed as unsupported.

If you search for the "GT-P7510", that's a Samsung Galaxy Tab Wi-Fi only tablet, and should answer your specific question.  However, given that you can eliminate devices for all sorts of reasons (display density, size, etc) it may be hard to figure out why, in general, a device isn't supported ...

Answer (score 1):

We answer this before.

it is like this:

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.CALL_PHONE"></uses-permission>
<uses-feature android:name="android.hardware.telephony" android:required="false"></uses-feature>
```

and here the full [dissociation](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10443964/my-app-is-not-available-for-tablet-device-on-google-play)

[other good answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11691775/why-my-app-is-not-showing-up-on-tablets-in-google-play)

Comment: Thanks, but how can I tell if my app is visible in Google Play to tablets, without actually buying one or calling up my client and asking him to check, there should be a way to check which devices will be able to see it. I may fix the phone problem only to have another issue blocking tablet access, what I would like is a way to know.

Comment: If you’re looking at Google Play, the best place to look for tablet-specific apps is to tap the “Staff Picks for Tablets” link. All of the apps listed there are optimized for tablets.

Another tip is to end app name in HD (High Definition) or XL (Extra Large); this is your clue the app was designed for tablets’ larger screens. Some apps will have a standard version and an HD version; as long as you install the HD version, so that let users know if the app work on tablet.

Comment: I'm not trying to let the users know that my app is optimized and available for their tablets. I have an app created primarily for phones, and I would like to know whether or not tablet users can see it on Google Play. Hopefully without actually having to buy a tablet, fire it up and check myself. Sorry if the question was unclear.

Answer (score 0):

Even better is going to the `Optimization Tips` side menu for your app on the `Developer Console`. The `To Do` tab will show you tips and provide links to further details on what features/permissions, like the phone calls mentioned above, are preventing your app from showing as available for tablets, etc.