# Misunderstanding Google Play says Your device isn't compatible with this version

Tags: android, google-play, google-play-services

**This question have a lot of responses already but none of it helps me**

I created an Android app and it says that I can't install it on tablet. If I run project from Android Studio on tablet it works perfectly.Also it doesn't find the app by name only on the tablet.

On desktop when open my app's page:
[image]

On tablet when open my app's page using a direct link:
[image]

My tablet has Android 4.4.2

in app gradle file:

```
 minSdkVersion 16
 targetSdkVersion 23
```

in app manifest I am using:

```
    <!--for IMEI -> is not a must to have gsm-->
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_WIFI_STATE" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_PHONE_STATE" />
<uses-feature
    android:name="android.hardware.telephony"
    android:required="false" />

<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.VIBRATE" />
<uses-permission android:name="com.google.android.c2dm.permission.RECEIVE"/>
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.DOWNLOAD_WITHOUT_NOTIFICATION" />
<uses-permission android:name="com.android.launcher.permission.INSTALL_SHORTCUT" />
<uses-permission android:name="com.android.launcher.permission.UNINSTALL_SHORTCUT" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION" />

<!--is not a must to have autofocus or even camera-->
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.CAMERA" />
<uses-feature
    android:name="android.hardware.camera"
    android:required="false" />
<uses-feature
    android:name="android.hardware.camera.autofocus"
    android:required="false" />

<!--to support all screens-->
<supports-screens
    android:anyDensity="true"
    android:largeScreens="true"
    android:normalScreens="true"
    android:smallScreens="true" />
```

Comment: Does your tablet have a camera?

Comment: Did check this [Support larger screens](http://stackoverflow.com/a/10444843/5955593)

Comment: yes my tablet have back and front camera, and gsm too

Comment: faced similar problem in past with multiple users.Any chance you have same user id registered on multiple phones/ tablets?

Comment: is not this I changd different accounts

Answer (score 0):

"For your app to be showcased in the 'Designed for tablets' list in the Play Store, you need to upload at least one 7-inch and one 10-inch screenshot. If you previously uploaded screenshots, make sure to move them into the right area below." This can be found when you are setting the distribution for your app on google play. If you do not provide a screenshot for this screen, Google will set your app just for phones.

Comment: I uploaded 3 pic for Phone / Tablet 7 / Tablet 10 sections

Comment: Ok... Check maybe you set it to be available for a specific country.

Answer (score 0):

Does your tablet have gps? If not you should probably add:

`<uses-feature android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION"
    android:required="false" />`

And also try adding `xlargeScreens` to true.

Answer (score 0):

Check if your tablet is set in supported devicess.

Go to Play Dev Console, then click on APK, then under supported devices click 'see list' and navigate to Samsung to check if your device is set.

Alternatively in same APK section click on your current app version and in popup, check if your language (and region) are supported in Localizations section.

Both cases might checkout to be OK, but never hurts to check :)